# python django allow users to post message

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I am new to python and django and I am trying to allow users to enter text into a texbox and when they click post, the message should show directly below the textbox. The user can choose between private message of public message using the radio button. If public it would say "username wrote: hello" if private it would say "username whispered: hello" this is what I have so far and I am currently stuck and keep giving an error "inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation (views.py, line 19)"

Comment: the 3rd line in views.py is not tabbed properly. `username = request.session['username']` also the error means that in some places you are using spaces, and in others you are using tabs '\t' != '    '... yea i just copy-pasted your stuff into an editor, and it seems like lines 4-12 are tab indented, and line 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

So i just hit "edit" on your post, and copy pasted it into my editor, and all the lines "-->" are tabs and all the pink dots are spaces.

be consistant, either use tabs or spaces ( [DONT USE TABS THOUGH AS ITS GENERALLY FROWNED UPON](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces)) ... also line 3 needs to be indented one more time.

As a rule of thumb, when editing python, i always view tabs and spaces. Most good IDEs will have this option. If its a python exclusive IDE, then it BETTER have this option :)

Answer (score 0):

```
username = request.session['username']
```

needs to be indented if it's supposed to be under that if block.